# NGINX Parsing and failing Content Security Policy on reload

Tags: nginx, centos6, content-security-policy

This is a server-side CSP question. In NGINX, I am having a number of issues reloading the config as my Content Security Policy header is giving me a difficult time.

```
[root@www1 ~]# service nginx reload
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "script-src" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:15
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I've rewritten and rewritten this policy probably 8 times, but NGINX will not accept it. NGINX version is nginx/1.10.2, CentOS 6.8, kernel 2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64

```
server {

[...] //Stuff

add_header Content-Security-Policy:"default-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://bam.nr-data.net https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://cdn.mxpnl.com https://ajax.cloudflare.com https://*.redacted.co;style-src 'self' https://*.redacted.co;img-src *;font-src 'self' https://*.redacted.co https://cloud.typography.com; object-src 'none';frame-src 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests;";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; ";
add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

[...] //Stuff

}
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I made an addition of a colon where there shouldn't have been. Removed and suddenly NGINX was happy.

`add_header Content-Security-Policy:` should be `add_header Content-Security-Policy`